# Windows Paths only disfunctional in batch context

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that builds a path, then cannot find the path.  Although if I try the exact same path from the command line, it works.  Here's some clunky code to illustrate my issue:

```
C:\batch>SET JAVA="I:\"
C:\batch>SET JAVA-LOCAL="J:\raw\java\"
C:\batch>SET CF005="V:\"
C:\batch>SET CF006="U:\"
C:\batch>SET CF005-local="J:\raw\cf\005\"
C:\batch>SET CF006-local="J:\raw\cf\006\"
C:\batch>SET CF-local="J:\raw\cf\"
C:\batch>SET REPORTS="J:\"
C:\batch>c:\cygwin\bin\grep -v "#" %CF006-local%ex%IISDT%.log > %CF-local%ex%IISDT%-temp.log
```

> **/usr/bin/grep: J:\raw\cf\006\ex150209.log : No such file or directory**

```
C:\batch>ls J:\raw\cf\006\ex150209.log
J:\raw\cf\006\ex150209.log
```

So you can see that the file can't be found initially, but when I reference it from the command line with 'ls', it seems suddenly available.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: echo c:\cygwin\bin\grep -v "#" %CF006-local%ex%IISDT%.log > %CF-local%ex%IISDT%-temp.log

Comment: If you have cygwin, why aren't you using bash?

Comment: Rob, that's a long and ugly story, and I agree completely with your sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know your definition of `%IISDT%` but the `%CF006-local%ex` results to `"J:\raw\cf\006\"ex`; analogously `%CF-local%ex`  results to `"J:\raw\cf\"ex`. Cannot become a valid base for a file name.

Your `set` commands should look as follows rather:

```
SET "JAVA=I:\"
SET "JAVA-LOCAL=J:\raw\java\"
SET "CF005=V:\"
:: and so on...
```

**Edit**: for debugging purposes

- use `set` without parameters to show environment variables;
- consider prefixing your own defined ones e.g. with `_` underscore:
  then `set _` shows  those only;
- in a batch script, use `echo on`

An `echo` example  (note `^` escaped `>` redirector for `echo` only):

```
echo -v "#" %CF006-local%ex%IISDT%.log ^> %CF-local%ex%IISDT%-temp.log
```

Resource:

- [CMD environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [Escaping special characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: Thanks JosefZ - I guess what threw me is that the error doesn't show the errant quotes.